# Event for input type=number

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs, input

I am a bit new to Angularjs. In Chrome, for number type input fields, pressing on up and down key arrow increases/decreases the entered value. It needs to be disabled. Any ideas or help in how it can be done?

I tried using jQuery: `$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function ()` but the ng-model binding is not updating. Might be because the angular js doesn't recognize the change made with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model won't change inside jquery event.Use ng-keypress event in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable it permanently better do it another way, use regular text input but restrict other chars than numbers.

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" />
```

Check out [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-model` directive to access the value of input in controller, and `ng-disabled` directive to control an input state. Hopefully the following demo may be of some help:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myNumber = 0;
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.isDisabled = !$scope.isDisabled;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="myNumber" ng-disabled="isDisabled"/>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Disable/Enable</button>
  </div>
</div>
```